# How to connect a client to a server through an HTTP proxy in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, server, client

I'm really new to coding using sockets.

I like the socket library, I get to understand a big part of what's happening in my program, so i you don't mind i would like to stick with it.

So as the title says, I have a socket based client and server and I would like to exchange content through an HTTP proxy(I'm using a Squid proxy). This little piece of code is supposed to bypass the proxy in my campus to simulate a chat over the campus network. This is totally legal since I asked the IT guys that work there.

Here's the deal, I am able to send a POST request through the proxy to my server which receives it and sends it back to client 1, but when I try to send more requests to the proxy none of them gets to the server so I think to my self the connection died but here's the thing, when I send messages from client 2 which is connected directly to the server, the server AND client 1 receive them.

```
import socket
from _thread import *

def sender(server,h):
    b=input("<<--Send--")
    b=h
    server.send(b.encode())

PROXY_IP="127.0.0.1"
PROXY_PORT=3128
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.settimeout(0.05)
server.connect((PROXY_IP,PROXY_PORT))

header="""POST http://127.0.0.1:3001 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 127.0.0.1:3001\r\n
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Content-Length: 5 \r\n\r\n
hello\r\n"""

server.send(header.encode())

while 1:
    try:
        start_new_thread(sender,(server,header))
        a=server.recv(1024)
        print("-->>{}".format(a.decode()))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except:
        pass

server.close()
```

I already tried the CONNECT method which works perfectly, but it's not allowed in my campus network proxy.
What am I doing wrong ?
Is there something I should know about how to re-send content through a proxy ?
Thank you for your time and please bear with me..

Here's what I get on the client that sends a request to the proxy:

```
~#Sent : POST http://127.0.0.1:3001 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:3001
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5 

hello

#Received : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: squid/3.5.19
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 00:46:39 GMT
X-Transformed-From: HTTP/0.9
X-Cache: MISS from kali
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from kali:3128
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 kali (squid/3.5.19)
Connection: keep-alive


#Received : B2
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 5
Host: 127.0.0.1:3001
Via: 1.1 kali (squid/3.5.19)
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
Cache-Control: max-age=259200
Connection: keep-alive

hello


#Sent : POST http://127.0.0.1:3001 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:3001
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5 

hello
```

Nothing is received after this..

Comment: A couple of questions:

1) Why not use `http.client` which is proxy-aware?
2) Can you provide the source with two requests on the same socket, where the second request fails to make it through the proxy?

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast ! Like i said i would really like to stick with the socket library to undestand what i'm doing before moving on to more elaborate ones. I edited the post with what you asked hoping this clears things up a bit..

Comment: The second request in your example looks wrong. Proxied requests must have full URL in first line of the request.
I.e. `POST http://127.0.0.1:3001/ HTTP/1.1` rather than `POST / HTTP/1.1`

Comment: the second one is the one that was sent from the proxy to the server and sent back to the client (There's a "Received :" for received replies) the first request is the same as the lasy one and is done automatically at start to establish a connection to te proxy

Answer (score 0):

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:3001 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: 127.0.0.1:3001\r\n
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Content-Length: 5 \r\n\r\n
hello\r\n
```

The body of your HTTP response consists of 7 bytes not 5 as you've stated in your `Content-length`. The `\r\n` after the 5 byte still belong to the response body. Giving the wrong size might mixup request handling, i.e. the proxy is expecting a new request but is actually getting `\r\n`, i.e. the 2 bytes after your 5 bytes `Content-length`.

Apart from that both path and `Host` header must include the name of the target from the perspective of the proxy. Using 127.0.0.1. like in your example would mean that you try to access a server at the same host of the proxy, i.e. localhost from the view of the proxy. This is probably not what you've intended.

```
...
X-Transformed-From: HTTP/0.9
```

This header in the response of the proxy indicates that your server does not properly speak HTTP/1.x. Instead of sending HTTP header and body it just sends the payload back without any HTTP header, like done in the HTTP 0.9 protocol which was obsoleted 20 years ago. With HTTP 0.9 the response will always end only at the end of the TCP connection. This means that you cannot have multiple requests within the same TCP connection.

> I'm really new to coding using sockets.

The problem is not caused by the wrong use of sockets but due the wrong implementation of the application protocol, i.e. the data send over the socket. If you really need to implement HTTP please study the standards, i.e. [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) and following. If you don't want to do this use existing and tested HTTP libraries instead of writing your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and your help ! I just added a response header HTTP/1.1 200 OK followed by the Content-Length in the server response and it worked magically.. Although the old connection is closed and a new one is create (with the server). Is this normal ? And I can't get messages coming from Client 2(which gets the messages from client 1)
(The proxy and the server are running locally just for the sake of testing)

Comment: @shirohige: I think you should put this in a new question with the current code and more details about the behavior instead of asking this follow-up question in a comment. Its impossible to say from this short description what you are really doing.